# Javascript + characters get removed when alerting encrypted string from cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, encryption, jquery-plugins

I have an encrypted string in a cookie, the string has been encrypted using CryptoJS. When i look at the cookie with a tool called CookiesManager, the cookie is normal. But when i alert it from the cookie all the + characters have been removed. I am using a jQuery plugin called [jQuery Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/). I have tried to set encoding to UTF-8, but the + characters are still removed.
Code(Js):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
var host = $.cookie("encrHost");
alert("Host: " + host);
</script>
```

What gets alerted:

> Host: U2FsdGVkX18vi2P/aWBEA4AzwE4 oMDFP2 tucKLyKk=

Cookies Manager Screen Shot:
[image: Cookies Manager]

Comment: I don't understand the problem, it's clear the cookie `encrHost` is an encrypted string. What do you need?

Comment: When i alert the contents of the cookie with javascript the + characters get removed, which means the encrypted string changes and cannot be decrypted anymore. And if it is alerted like that, it means it is not the alert function that removes the + characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because by default the cookie is url encoded as stated in the plugin homepage:

> By default the cookie value is encoded/decoded when writing/reading, using encodeURIComponent/decodeURIComponent. Bypass this by setting raw to true:
>
> ```
> $.cookie.raw = true;
> ```

So just add `$.cookie.raw = true` before you call it and you should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, i will try It later